# Bloquear campos em SubForms em MS Access

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Tenho a seguinte Form com uma SubForm:

[image: Form com SuForm]

E preciso de habilitar o Check em "Aprove3" e bloquear os outros campos, mas apenas consigo "LOCK" todos ou nenhum, como posso dar a volta? Talvez por vba?
Lembro que é uma SubForm dentro de uma Form

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando a formatação condicional você consegue bloquear/habilitar um campo à partir de um critério:

[image: Formatação condicional no Access]

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Alterar-a-apar%C3%AAncia-de-um-controle-usando-a-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-condicional-6ba9e9fa-4347-4183-b335-44e43b05e22f

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/83397)

Comment: Verdade @Taisbevalle, corrigirei isso